# How do I convert multiple columns to individual rows/values if there is no other unique column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science, backend

Following is the example

| Rates, values 2019Q01 | Rates, values 2019Q02 | Rates, values 2019Q03 | Rates, values 2019Q04 | Sales, values 2019Q01 | Sales, values 2019Q02 | Sales, values 2019Q03 | Sales, values 2019Q04 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 150 | 200 | 300 | 400 | 450 | 500 | 600 |

Resultant should be

| Period | Rates, values | Sales, values |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019Q01 | 100 | 400 |
| 2019Q02 | 150 | 450 |
| 2019Q03 | 200 | 500 |
| 2019Q04 | 300 | 600 |

I've tried melt and wide_to_long, but unable to get the result. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try via `columns` attribute and then `stack()`:

```
df.columns=df.columns.str.replace('values','').str.split(', ',expand=True)
df=df.stack().droplevel(0).rename_axis(index='Period').add_suffix(', values').reset_index()
```

OR as suggested by [`@Cytorak`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5431791/cyttorak)

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.rsplit(' ', 1, expand=True)
df=df.stack().droplevel(0).rename_axis(index='Period').reset_index()
```

output of `df`:

```
    Period      Rates, values   Sales, values
0   2019Q01     100             400
1   2019Q02     150             450
2   2019Q03     200             500
3   2019Q04     300             600
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I want , values as well, I don't want to replace it

Comment: Would suggest the following as the first line: `df.columns = df.columns.str.rsplit(' ', 1, expand=True)`

Comment: @AnuragDabas  In my resultant table I'm getting last column name Unnamed: with NaN values for each row. Do you know why it is coming and how can I remove it?

Comment: @Cyttorak Read the previous comment please.

Comment: @SSS Sir use `df=df.dropna(axis=1,how='all')`